# How to view which mysql authentication plugin a user's password is using?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I created two users, both of which use 2 different authentication plugins:

```sql
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'rachel' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'super_secure_password';

CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'bob' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'amazing_password';
```

Note how the users are using 2 different authentication plugins:

- User `rachel` is using `mysql_native_password`
- User `bob` is using `caching_sha2_password`

How can I query mysql to retrieve this information about my users?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`select user, plugin from mysql.user;`